# http- and https-Links open in different browsers in Windows 10 update 1607

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, default-settings, windows-10-v1607

I have recently upgraded my Windows 10 machine to the latest build 1607, and notice the following behaviour: when I click on a link in my Email program (Outlook 2010), it opens the links in different browsers depending on wether you click a http Link (opens in Firefox), or a https Link (opens in Chrome).

My default app configured as "Webbrowser" is Firefox. How and where can I chose which browser to use for different link types? I cannot find any setting anywhere in Windows 10 to influence that behaviour.

Comment: Can you make Firefox open HTTPS links via `Settings -> System -> Default apps -> either "Choose default apps by protocol" or "Set defaults by app -> select firefox -> Choose defaults for this program"`?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that Microsoft did not make all settings accessible in the new settings dialog, however, they have a chaotic system of "old settings" and "new settings" mixed up, some redundant, some only in the old, some only in the new dialog. I wonder how they convinced their quality guys to publish a state like that at all.

Nvertheless, there still is the old system-settings-dialog, and under  `Programs -> Default Programs -> Set Default app`, you can easily set default apps by extension type, or protocol type, not only for the webbrowser, but also for like example your image viewer, so that you can set a different viewer for png and jpg files for example.